# sufficient condition for complement graph to be connected

Tags: graph-theory

Good evening guys.

Q. Graph G' is a complement graph of Graph G, let's say G' is connected. Then prove sufficient condition for "G' to be a connected graph" is "G is not connected".

A. I plotted lots of sample case and it seems to be a self-explanatory. But I don't know how to prove it in mathematical way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a non-connected graph. Let $H$ and $K$ be two connected components. For $h\in H$ and $k\in K$ there is no path from $h$ to $k$ in $G$, in particular the are **not** connected by an edge. This means that in the complement $G‘$ they **are** connected by an edge. In other words, any two vertices from distinct components in $G$ are connected by an edge in $G‘$.

Now given $h,h‘$ in the same component $H$ of $G$ there is some vertex $k$ in another component $K$ (since $G$ is assumed to be disconnected), thus $h\sim k\sim h‘$ provides a path from $h$ to $h‘$ in $G‘$.

In summary any two vertices in $G‘$ are connected by a path.